# Jqgrid issue with footer text format

Tags: jqgrid

In Jqgrid for some columns I have set as link.
And also for those columns I have set footer (MAX).
But the issue is, configured link is also getting added to the footer value, which is not expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is **how** you add the footer information. If you use [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) you can use `false` as the last parameter (the `format` parameter) of [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). In the case the footer data will not be formatted by the standard formatter of the corresponding column. As the example see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinksWithFooter.htm).

If you add the data from the server using [userdata](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#user_data) and use [userDataOnFooter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) jqGrid option the formatter parameter will be alway used as `true` (see the source code of jqGrid [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L1163) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L1331)). As a workaround you can remove `userDataOnFooter:true` setting and add the footer information manually with respect of [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) inside your `localComplete` event handle:

```
var myGrid = $("#list"); // your grid
// ...

// inside of localComplete you can add the data
var userData = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam","userData");
myGrid.jqGrid("footerData","set",userData,false);
```

Comment: i used custom hyperlink formatter insted of `'showlink'`. actually i put a `onclick` function to the <a> tag inside my formatter.i was worrying about how i can remove the formatting in the total row of that hyperlink column. This was really helpful and it works. Thanks a lot Oleg.

Comment: @Sam: I am glad to read that I could help you. You are welcome!

Comment: @iPeleg: I'm glad that the old answer could help you. The user **kiruthika** who wrote the question was seen on the stackoverflow two years ago (at 4 Feb 2013). So the answer will be probably never accepted.