# jqGrid custom formatter for userData

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, user-data, jqgrid-formatter

Is there any workaround to add custom 'formatter' to `userData` in jqGrid? i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878900/jqgrid-issue-with-footer-text-format) question and it helps me a lot. below is the code that i use to populate jqGrid. please note that i populate a custom `userData` object in the `jsonReader` and set it to the grid in `loadComplete` i need to add separate 'formatter' to total columns. please let me know if there is a way. Thanks in advance.

```
var userDataTotals;
jq("#testGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'local',
    datatype: 'local',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:[
              'rowId','unitId',
              '<fmt:message key="report.col1"/>',
              '<fmt:message key="report.col2"/>',
    ],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'rowId', index:'rowId',hidden: true,sortable: true,key:true}, 
        {name:'unitId', index:'unitId',hidden: true,sortable: true,key:true}, 
        {name:'outboundReadyDate', index:'outboundReadyDate', width:80,align:"center",sorttype:'integer',formatter:dateOnlyFmatter,datefmt:'Y M d'},
        {name:'outboundDate', index:'outboundDate', width:80,align:"center",sorttype:'integer',formatter:dateOnlyFmatter,datefmt:'Y M d'},
    ],
    // this will enable the footer row to display totals
    footerrow : true,
    //userDataOnFooter : true,
    altRows : true,
    //to hide pager buttons
    pgbuttons:false,
    recordtext:'',
    pgtext:'',
    gridview: true,
    height:270,
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'rowId',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum:30000,
    loadComplete: function() {
        // This will increase the column header height ( to show two rows in the header)
        jq(".ui-jqgrid-sortable").css('white-space', 'normal');
        jq(".ui-jqgrid-sortable").css('height', 'auto');
        //Set the total values after load complete,otherwise
        // custom formatter will format the total value as well.

        jq("#mainReportGrid").jqGrid("footerData","set",userDataTotals,false);

        //check the data type to avoid this code to  execute when the pageload
        var checkDatatype = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam","datatype");
        if(checkDatatype =='json' && myGrid.getGridParam('records') == 0){
            // when no records are displaying alert it to the user
            alert(noRecordsMsg);
        }

    },

    jsonReader : {
        root: "dtos",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: "cell",
        id: "rowId",
        userdata :function(obj) {
            userDataTotals = {"outboundReadyDate":obj.totalOutBounded,
                "outboundDate":obj.totalOutBoundReady};
        }

    },


    //This will format the date of the grid (without displaying time)
    function dateOnlyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject){
        var opts = options.colModel.formatoptions;
        if(cellvalue==null || cellvalue=='undefined'){
            return '-';
        }else{
            if(opts != undefined && rowObject.projectTypeName =='IOD'){
                return 'N/A';   
            }
            var now = new Date(cellvalue);
            return now.format('M j, Y');
        }
    }
```

i use custom `dateFormat.js` to format the date.

and the json Response is -

```
{
    "dtos": [
        {
            "unitId": 1068,
            "outboundDate": null,
            "outboundReadyDate": 1317619303000,
            "rowId": 13,
        },
        {
            "unitId": 1105,
            "outboundDate": 1317616970000,
            "outboundReadyDate": 1317617213000,
            "rowId": 14,
        }
    ],
    "totalOutBounded": 0,
    "totalOutBoundReady": 4,
    "rowTotal": 15,
    "returnCode": 0,
    "msg": ""
}
```

i used `sortType` as `integer` because from the server i am passing a 'java' `Date` object directly to the grid. in order to sort it i need to set `sortType` to `integer`

Basic problem what i am having was in IE8  i cannot see the 'userData' total values. but in other browsers i can see it. i need to format `userData` total values as 'hyperlinks'.

without `userData` formatting i can see the totals in IE8. so that i am thinking that without using the column `'formatter'` adding a custom formatter to the total values (`userData`).

Comment: Could you include the code of the `dateOnlyFmatter`?

Comment: Other strings like `datefmt:'Y M d'` and `sorttype:'integer'` looks very strange and suspected. Could you include the JSON data which you post? One clear error is the usage of `key:true` for more as one column.

Comment: @oleg - Thanks for the respond oleg. please find the 'dateOnlyFmatter' code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many small syntax errors:

- The usage of trailing comma (like ',}') is a syntax error. You have to remove trailing comma from JSON data and from `colNames` and `colModel`. The `"rowId": 13,}` and `"rowId": 14,}` can't be read.
- You define `jQuery("#testGrid")`, but use `jQuery("#mainReportGrid")` to set the footer.
- The `url: 'local'` or any other `url` parameter has no sense in case of `datatype: 'local'`. The `url` parameter will be just ignored (not used) in case of `datatype: 'local'`.
- You use `myGrid` which you not defined in the posted code. Either you should define `var myGrid = jQuery("#testGrid");` somewhere at the beginning of your code or define `var myGrid = $(this);` at the beginning of `loadComplete` event handler.
- You use `now.format('M j, Y')` and not post the extension method `format` of the `Date`. You can use jqGrid method instead: `return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(undefined, now, 'M j, Y', $.jgrid.formatter.date);`.
- I recommend you to use strict equality `===` always instead of `==` and `!==` instead of `!=`. Read for example [here](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#eqeq) for more information.
- I recommend you to use `height: 'auto'` or `scrollOffset: 0` if you use jqGrid *without* having scroll bars.
- I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642433/jqgrid-click-local-data-column-sort-client-side-only-wipes-userdata-on-grid-ref/7658590#7658590). If you use the described bug fix you can modify the line `jq("#mainReportGrid").jqGrid("footerData","set",userDataTotals,false);` to the line

  `myGrid.jqGrid("footerData", "set", myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData'), false);`

  The variable `userDataTotals` will be not needed and the method `userdata` from the `userdata` can be defined as

  `userdata: function (obj) {
      return {
          outboundReadyDate: obj.totalOutBounded,
          outboundDate: obj.totalOutBoundReady
      };
  }`

You can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithUserDataCustomFormatter.htm) modified version of your code.

Comment: @Oleg- Thanks for millions for pointing out my errors. i will fix those.setting 'userData' and using the ' $.jgrid.formatter.date' is really helpfull. i will post my comments about the IE8 issue once i fix and test all the errors you pointed out.Thank you very much again Oleg.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille & Oleg - i am really sorry i took this much of time to accept this answer.