# jqgrid click local data column sort (client-side only) wipes userData on grid refresh

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, multi-select, user-data

I have a grid that is populated by a JSON response (MVC3 controller) that has a userData component for some additional data for grid captions, etc.  All that works just fine.  I recently switched the the grid's data loading to "loadonce: true" as in working with larger grid results sets, I wanted client-side sorting and filtering.  All that works good.  BUT, I was surprised that the userData got wiped the first time I clicked any column for sorting.  If I turn off loadonce, userData is fine, but it is of course going back to the server each time.  The items that make use of the userData fire on gridcomplete and are now coming back "undefined" after a sort (and probably anything that reloads the grid).  Any thoughts why this might be happening?  Oh yeah, I also noticed that clicking a column sort wiped out any multiselections (perhaps related to the same culprit?).

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to make 1 AJAX call and retrieve your grid data, and some other data. You also want to do sorting and filtering all on the client side. Is that correct?


I've never used the userData property of the grid, but it looks like the purpose of it is so that you can do one AJAX call and get back a couple of different sets of data, 1 for the binding the grid, and 1 for binding other HTML controls on your page.

Comment: Oleg pegged it.  userData is like a ASP.Net MVC3 Viewbag.  Best I can tell it is only used in data payloads coming from the server.  I am using a JsonResult, but I suppose it could come by other means as well.  Very handy facility.  In my case, I wanted additional data items from the database for captions and what not, but disliked the notion of having to crowd the colModel with a bunch of additional hidden columns.  I was sending back a JsonResult and it was easy enough to add in the userData collection to the server side JSON object before serializing it.  Some practical restrictions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. +1 from me. It's a jqGrid bug. Inside of internal `addLocalData` method after [the line 1527](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L1527) of the file grid.base.js of jqGrid 4.1.2 or after the 1532 of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (you can get modified version from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-userdata.js)) one should add the following line

```
retresult[ts.p.localReader.userdata] = ts.p.userData;
```

It will fix the problem. I posted the corresponding bug report [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/userdata-parameter-will-be-deleted-after-the-first-load-in-case-of-loadoncetrue/#p24813).

Comment: Thanks @Oleg!!  I figured it was a bug as during other events, the noew localized data was being preserved.

Comment: @Mark J Bailey: The bug is already [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/9feed27e3aab048468af90c0c6bd2d258f061208) in the main code of jqGrid on the github. So the next version of jqGrid will definitively have the fix which you need.